# Increasing number of threads decreases cpu performance

Tags: multithreading

I have written a program that tries to do some calculations. It can be run any number of cores.

Below it's a breakdown on how many calculations are performed if it's run on 1,2,3,4 cores (on a 4 logical processors laptop). The numbers in parenthesis show calculations per thread/core. My question is why the performance decreases very rapidly then number of threads/cores increases ? I dont expect the performance to double but it's significantly lower. I also observer the same issue when running 4 instance of the same program setup to run on one thread so i know that it's not an issue with the program it self.
The greatest improvement is going form 1 thread to 2 why is that ?

```
# Threads | calculations/sec
1         | 87000
2         | 129000 (65000,64000)
3         | 135000 (46000,45000,44000)
4         | 140000 (34000,34000,34000,32000)
```

One interesting thing is that exactly the same issue i can see on Google Cloud Platform in Compute Engine, when I run the program on 16 threads on 16 **virtual cores** platform the performance of each core drops down to like 8K states per second. However if I run 16 instances of the same program each instance does around 100K states /s. When I do the same test but on 4 cores on my home laptop i can still see the same drop of performance whether I run 4 separate .exe of one with 4 cores, I was expecting to see the same behavior on GCP but it's not the case, is it because of **virtual cores** ? do they behave differently.

Example code that reproduces this issue, just need to paste to your console application, but need to refresh the stats like 20 times for the performance to stabilize, not sure why it fluctuates so much. [code example](http://pastebin.com/hUXKkGUx) you can see that if you run the app with with 4 threads the you get significant performance impact compared to 4 instances with 1 thread each. I was hoping that that enabling gcServer will solver the problem but did not see any improvement

Comment: You should provide a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it is very difficult to answer. Many factors can make you program slower with several threads. If the size of the problem is not large enough, thread creation can dominate processing time. If you have many mutex, critical sections, etc, it can also significantly slow down your performances. You can have many false sharing in your code, etc.

Comment: Sub-linear speedup is more the rule than the exception.  Remember that even though each core runs more-or-less independently of the other cores, other resources (e.g. RAM) are still shared between cores, so unless all your code and data can fit into each core's L1 cache, the likelihood is that cores start to spend some of their time waiting for their turn to read or write to RAM, and this overhead increases with the number of active threads.

Comment: @AlainMerigot the problem is actually very big it's solving Eternity puzzle 2 but the program is designed is such a way there is not critical section, each thread works on it's own data set, and no data is shared between threads. There  is no mutex. One interesting thing is that exactly the same issue i can see on Google Clout Platform in Compute Engine, when I run the program on 16 threads on 16 **virtual cores** platform the performance of each core drops down to like 8K states per second. However if I run 16 instances of the same program each instance does around 100K states /s

Comment: You are using a resource that doesn't scale with the number of cores.  That's quite normal, could be memory or the disk.  The big drop from 2 to 3 is easy to explain on a processor with 2 cores that has hyper-threading enabled.

Comment: @Hans Passant this does not explain why in multi exe case I don't see the performance degradation as with multi threaded.

Comment: OP posted some code on IRC: they were using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to start the threads, which will introduce a bottleneck while the ThreadPool spins up new threads (up to 12 seconds for 16 workers). However they said they were unwilling to post the code which actually does the work, and without it I think this is unanswerable. Voting to close.

Comment: I did some more testing and it turns out that in multi exe case I also get application performance degradation but it's much less.

Comment: E.g. with 16 .exe files it ends up with 80K states visited per second for each Solver but when I run one exe with 16 threads, each Solver visits about 8K states that in big difference. @canton7 I have told you already on IRC that the bottleneck at the beginning due to thread pool is irrelevant. When I test I run it for few minutes and all threads are running. I'll try to get some code shortly.

Comment: i tried the `<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <gcServer enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
    ...
</configuration> ` setting but did not make much difference, trying to come up example code to reproduce this

Comment: Example code that reproduces this issue, just need to paste to your console application, but need to refresh the stats like 20 times for the performance to stabilize, not sure why it fluctuates so much. https://pastebin.com/hUXKkGUx  you can see that if you run the app with with 4 threads the you get significant performance impact compared to 4 instances with 1 thread each. I was hoping that that enabling gcServer will solver the problem but did not see any improvement